# Selenium not inputing strings based on name?

Tags: c#, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

Im trying to create some tests in C# visual studio with selenium. When I run the test, google chrome navigates to the specified website, however no keys/strings are entered into the username and password fields...

Why is this? How do I fix this?  How can I create a test which has the user enter the correct username and password queries and click on the submit form.

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;


namespace test
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver("/Users/name/Desktop/test/");

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://newtours.demoaut.com/mercurywelcome.php");

            IWebElement username = driver.FindElement(By.Name("userName"));
            username.SendKeys("mercury");

            IWebElement password = driver.FindElement(By.Name("password"));
            password.SendKeys("mercury");

            var signIn = driver.FindElement(By.Name("login"));
            signIn.Submit();


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Page loading is taking some time.so, please add some wait after navigating to the URL.

Add the below NuGet Package in your test and modified the code as below

**NuGet package:**
DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers

Additonal NameSpace declarration,

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI; //for the wait method
using SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers;  //for the expected conditions method
```

**Working Code:**

```
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://newtours.demoaut.com/mercurywelcome.php");

    var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.TitleContains("Welcome"));//It will wait until the page load completion 

    IWebElement username = driver.FindElement(By.Name("userName"));
    username.SendKeys("mercury");
```

Comment: @Novice_29: Please check with the answer .If this answer is helpful, then please accept the answer by clicking on the tick arrow button and give the upvote by clicking on the up arrow button